# In iOS 5 with iPhone 3gs, glDrawElements success. But In iOS 6 with iPhone 5, it throw crash

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios6, crash, exc-bad-access

I have developed a OpenGL ES 2.0 program in iPhone 3GS with iOS 5.1. It use `glDrawElements` OpenGl function.

In iPhone 3GS, this code successfully returned. But in iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.2, throw `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I don't know why. I call glDrawElements with indices. Small scale mesh data is well processed in both iPhone 3gs and iPhone 5. But large scale mesh data is fale in iPhone 5.

`EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` is thrown in "`gleRunVertexSubmitARM`"

Show me the tips.

Below is the code.
Help me.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0, (void*)&mesh2->vertices[0][0]); // ES 2.0

glEnableVertexAttribArray(_normalSlot);
glVertexAttribPointer(_normalSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0, (void*)&mesh->normals[0][0]); // ES 2.0

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh2->faces.size()*3,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &mesh2->faces[0].indices[0]); // <= Crash in iPhone5.
```

Comment: _positionSlot and _normalSlot is linked with shader's slot.     _positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
_normalSlot   = glGetAttribLocation(program,"a_normal");

Comment: Why are normals from other mesh, then verices and faces?

Comment: I have reconstructed new normals with original normal data in mesh2, and save it to mesh. This code is well runned in iPhone 3GS, but not in iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The code what in question is perfect. I have find that glDisableVertexAttribArray is not pairly called after glEnableVertexAttribArray in other source code. I fix it, and well run. 
Thank you.